# getting a timestamp out of a gwt-rpc string

Tags: json

i have a response from a server, which looks like:

```
//OK[0,1,"UpoNlmA",3,5,4,"UpoNlmA",3,2,0,1,"UpoUdDA",3,5,4,"UpoUdDA",3,2,0,1,"UpoZCBA",3,5,4,"UpoZCBA",3,2,0,1,"UpoJAoA",3,5,4,"UpoJNUg",3,2,0,1,"UpoLTHA",3,5,4,"UpoLdHo",3,2,0,1,"UpoSKkA",3,5,4,"UpoSKkA",3,2,0,1,"UpoP4FA",3,5,4,"UpoP4FA",3,2,0,1,"UpoWviA",3,5,4,"UpoWviA",3,2,8,1,["java.util.ArrayList/4159755760","com.initka.onlineinfo.server.datamodel.DepartureInformation/276724449","java.util.Date/3385151746","city","xyz"],0,7]
```

my reseach led me to the assumption that this is a GWT-RPC response. the question is now, how i can unserialize this strings `"UpoP4FA"` which used to be timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Google Web Toolkit encodes longs in RPC. Also timestamps are encoded in this format.

The encoding is pretty simple: Instead of the alphabet 0123456789 (as used for decimals, base 10) the alphabet here is ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_$ and the base is 64.

Here is a python snippet to decode a number encoded like this:

```
def from_gwt_long(inp):
    base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_$"
    return sum(base.index(inp[p]) * (len(base) ** (len(inp) - p - 1)) for p in range(len(inp)))
```

You can also put the alphabet given above into this base converter: http://elenzil.com/esoterica/baseConversion.html

Comment: I recently had to use something like that to decode date and I was able to decode any date after 1970 with a function like that and then adding the result to 1970-01-01, but the problem is with dates before 1970, I wasn't able to figure out a way to decode them, the string always starts with "P___", if I ignore this part and subtract the result it gives me a wrong date, and if I decode the whole string and add the result to 0001-01-01 the resulting date goes beyond the year 9999, any idea how GWT decodes dates before the Epoch base date?

Comment: i have noticed, that the base alphabet in fact is wrong. so in my case, the dollar sign has to go before the underscore, i.e:

   base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$_"

Answer (score 0):

```
function decodeTime($sTime) {
    $sBase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_$";
    $iSum = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($sTime); $i++) {
        $iSum += strpos($sBase, $sTime{$i}) * pow(strlen($sBase), strlen($sTime) - $i - 1);
    }
    return $iSum / 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

void DecodeTime()

{

string str = "UpoUdDA";

string Base ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_$";

Int64 Sum = 0;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Base.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Base[j] == str[i])
                {
                    Sum += j * Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(Base.Length, str.Length - i - 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Sum/1000))));
```

}

You can use above code to decode the strings like "UpoUdDA".

Answer (score 0):

For `java.util.Date/1659716317` (different from the format in the question; probably old, I see some mention of 2010 in the web application), one might see things like:

```
//OK[1,0,0,0,8,1.473173782528E12,5.15763472E8,7,635 ...
```

Here, the JavaScript date is created using:

```
new Date(1.473173782528E12 + 5.15763472E8);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java this decoding would be

```
static long longFromBase64(String value) {
    int pos = 0;
    long longVal = base64Value(value.charAt(pos++));
    int len = value.length();
    while (pos < len) {
      longVal <<= 6;
      longVal |= base64Value(value.charAt(pos++));
    }
    return longVal;
}

static int base64Value(char digit) {
    if (digit >= 'A' && digit <= 'Z') {
      return digit - 'A';
    }
    // No need to check digit <= 'z'
    if (digit >= 'a') {
      return digit - 'a' + 26;
    }
    if (digit >= '0' && digit <= '9') {
      return digit - '0' + 52;
    }
    if (digit == '$') {
      return 62;
    }
    // digit == '_'
    return 63;

}
```